# JavaScript. Удаление из DOM с отражением на массив

Tags: javascript, массивы, json, объекты, методы

Есть локальный `JSON` вывожу его в дерево.

Так же добавляю три `input`-а. Вешаю обработчик на `input` Удалить. И он удаляет из дерева. Хотелось бы что бы он так же удалял и из массива объект. Знаю про метод `splice(n,n)` но не понимаю как его прикрутить. Подскажите пожалуйста. Если будет нужно, то могу показать `JS`. Думал так же о том чтобы создать новый массив объектов из оставшихся после удаления элементов. И присвоить его старым массивом. Но так же не достаточно опыта.

```js
var data = JSON.parse(`{
  "task": [{
      "task_name": "Task # 1",
      "task_description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi, itaque?",
      "task_date": "1993-11-22"
    },
    {
      "task_name": "Task # 2",
      "task_description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi, itaque?",
      "task_date": "1993-11-22"
    },
    {
      "task_name": "Task # 3",
      "task_description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi, itaque?",
      "task_date": "1993-11-22"
    }
  ]
}`);

console.log(data.task);

var main_block = document.getElementById('main_task');

function showTask() {
  main_block.innerHTML = '';
  for (var i in data.task) {
    main_block.innerHTML += `
              <div class="element_task" data-state='now'>
                <h3> ${data.task[i].task_name} </h3>
                <br/>
                <p> ${data.task[i].task_description} </p>
                <hr/>
                <span style='display:none;'>${data.task[i].task_date}</span>
                <input type="submit" name="" value="Изменить">
                <input type="submit" name="" value="Выполнить">
                <input type="submit" name="delTask" value="Удалить">
              </div>`
  };
};
showTask();


function checkStatus() {
  var blockNow = document.getElementById('main_task');
  var elementTask = document.getElementsByClassName('element_task');
  for (var i = 0; i < elementTask.length; i++) {
    if (elementTask[i].getAttribute('data-state') == 'now') {
      var dataState = elementTask[i];
      dataState.onclick = function(event) {
        var target = event.target;
        if (target.getAttribute('name') != 'delTask') return;
        deleteTask(this);

      };
    };
  };

  function deleteTask(node) {
    blockNow.removeChild(node);
    rewrite();
  };

  // ТУТ СЕЙЧАС РАБОТАЮ ЧТО ТО ПРОБУЮ

  function rewrite() {
    var elems = blockNow.getElementsByTagName('div');
    elems = Array.prototype.slice.call(elems);
    for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
      var h3 = elems[i].getElementsByTagName('h3');
      h3 = Array.prototype.slice.call(h3);
      for (var i = 0; i < h3.length; i++) {
        h3 = h3[i].innerHTML
        console.log(h3);
      }
      console.log(h3);

    }
    console.log(data.task);
  };

};

checkStatus();
```

```html
<div id="main_task"></div>
```

Comment: Добавьте javscript код в вопрос

Comment: Добавил, в верху

Comment: Нужно делать наоборот, что бы удаляя из массива пропадал и `DOM` элемент. Смотрите в сторону `MVVM`

Comment: Спасибо! Начну копать...

Comment: Я не совсем понял что ты хочешь сделать. Сейчас ты удалил только саму кнопку. А хотел удалить весь таск? и плюсом удалить соответствующий объект из `data.task`?

Comment: я удаляю не одну кнопку а полностью узел (element_task). И да мне при этом нужно удалять объект из data.task тот же который выводился в узел

Comment: @EvilFox, а, точно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы удалить соответствующий элемент из массива - нужно как-то сопоставить элемент в DOM с элементом массива.

Самый простой случай, при создании разметки добавить элементу атрибут с индексом

```
<div class="element_task" data-state='now' data-task-index="${i}">
```

И в методе удаления просто удалить элемент по этому индексу, например

```js
var data = JSON.parse(`{
  "task": [{
      "task_name": "Task # 1",
      "task_description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi, itaque?",
      "task_date": "1993-11-22"
    },
    {
      "task_name": "Task # 2",
      "task_description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi, itaque?",
      "task_date": "1993-11-22"
    },
    {
      "task_name": "Task # 3",
      "task_description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi, itaque?",
      "task_date": "1993-11-22"
    }
  ]
}`);

var main_block = document.getElementById('main_task');

function showTask() {
  main_block.innerHTML = '';
  for (var i in data.task) {
    main_block.innerHTML += `
              <div class="element_task" data-state='now' data-task-index=${i}>
                <h3> ${data.task[i].task_name} </h3>
                <br/>
                <p> ${data.task[i].task_description} </p>
                <hr/>
                <span style='display:none;'>${data.task[i].task_date}</span>
                <input type="submit" name="" value="Изменить">
                <input type="submit" name="" value="Выполнить">
                <input type="submit" name="delTask" value="Удалить">
              </div>`
  };
};
showTask();


function checkStatus() {
  var blockNow = document.getElementById('main_task');
  var elementTask = document.getElementsByClassName('element_task');
  for (var i = 0; i < elementTask.length; i++) {
    if (elementTask[i].getAttribute('data-state') == 'now') {
      var dataState = elementTask[i];
      dataState.onclick = function(event) {
        var target = event.target;
        if (target.getAttribute('name') != 'delTask') return;
        deleteTask(this);

      };
    };
  };

  function deleteTask(node) {
    blockNow.removeChild(node);
    rewrite(node.dataset.taskIndex);
  };

  // ТУТ СЕЙЧАС РАБОТАЮ ЧТО ТО ПРОБУЮ

  function rewrite(index) {
    data.task.splice(index, 1);
    console.log(data.task);
  };

};

checkStatus();
```

```html
<div id="main_task"></div>
```

Но данный вариант ненадежен. Так как при удалении индексы будут сбиваться.

Вместо индекса можно использовать какое-нибудь уникальное поле, например `task_name`. В этом случае перед удалением нужно будет сначала найти индекс объекта, и лишь затем удалить. Либо заменить массив отфильтрованным и заново вызвать методы `showTask` и `checkStatus`

```js
var data = JSON.parse(`{
  "task": [{
      "task_name": "Task # 1",
      "task_description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi, itaque?",
      "task_date": "1993-11-22"
    },
    {
      "task_name": "Task # 2",
      "task_description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi, itaque?",
      "task_date": "1993-11-22"
    },
    {
      "task_name": "Task # 3",
      "task_description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi, itaque?",
      "task_date": "1993-11-22"
    }
  ]
}`);

var main_block = document.getElementById('main_task');

function showTask() {
  main_block.innerHTML = '';
  for (var i in data.task) {
    main_block.innerHTML += `
              <div class="element_task" data-state='now' data-task-name="${data.task[i].task_name}">
                <h3> ${data.task[i].task_name} </h3>
                <br/>
                <p> ${data.task[i].task_description} </p>
                <hr/>
                <span style='display:none;'>${data.task[i].task_date}</span>
                <input type="submit" name="" value="Изменить">
                <input type="submit" name="" value="Выполнить">
                <input type="submit" name="delTask" value="Удалить">
              </div>`
  };
};
showTask();


function checkStatus() {
  var blockNow = document.getElementById('main_task');
  var elementTask = document.getElementsByClassName('element_task');
  for (var i = 0; i < elementTask.length; i++) {
    if (elementTask[i].getAttribute('data-state') == 'now') {
      var dataState = elementTask[i];
      dataState.onclick = function(event) {
        var target = event.target;
        if (target.getAttribute('name') != 'delTask') return;
        deleteTask(this);

      };
    };
  };

  function deleteTask(node) {
    blockNow.removeChild(node);
    rewrite(node.dataset.taskName);
  };

  // ТУТ СЕЙЧАС РАБОТАЮ ЧТО ТО ПРОБУЮ

  function rewrite(taskName) {
    /* вариант со splice */
    // data.task.splice(data.task.findIndex(t => t.task_name == taskName), 1);

    /* вариант с фильтром */

    data.task = data.task.filter(t => t.task_name != taskName);
    showTask();
    checkStatus();

    console.log(data.task);
  };

};

checkStatus();
```

```html
<div id="main_task"></div>
```

Comment: Шикарно! Спасибо большое! Все довольна просто и понятно. Вот что значит опыт. Буду использовать метод splice. Так как task_name может повториться. Можно конечно добавить поле task_id в массив и делать выбор по нему. Но пока меня сильно волновало только вообщем как обратиться в массив как связать DOM с этим массивом. И добавление атрибута с индексом замечательный пример который я и искал. В дальнейшем когда решу оставшуюся часть задач обязательно перепишу на task_id как во втором примере. Еще раз спасибо! Очень благодарен!

Comment: @EvilFox, обрати внимание, что при удалении не последнего элемента, индексы надо будет переписывать иначе они начинают разъезжаться

Comment: Да я заметил что если удалять с первого по второй то при оставшимся третий в массив попадает второй. Хотя его удалили. Но пока это не страшный для меня баг. Я перепишу на task_id чуть позже